# Android App has Limited Supported Devices Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

Ok, I released an app I made to Play Store, but it seems my app is only compatible with a few devices. I am used to releasing for Apple, so I have no idea what in my manifest could be excluding so many devices. There are no popular devices supported :(

I would love some help figuring out what to change in my manifest to fix this?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="com.########" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your app build.gradle file in Android Studio and check minSdkVersion under default configuration and set API Level for minimum android api Version

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.sociallogin"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
        'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
   core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Play Console tells you exactly how you are limiting audience with your Manifest.

Open Google Play console > Release Management > App Releases > Manage Production > in the list of APKs, click the (i) icon on the right of the release's apk, you should see the uploaded manifest requirements like:

> APK details - com.example
>  Supported Android devices **11515**
>   devices 
>  API levels **15+** 
>  Target SDK **23** 
>  Screen
>   layouts **4 screen layouts**
>  Localizations default + 115 languages
>   
>  Features **2 features**
>  Required permissions **41
>   permissions**
>  OpenGL ES versions 1.0+ 
>  OpenGL textures all
>   textures
>   Native platforms **armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86 **

Note the parameters i've marked as bold in your apk, and compare them to your project's manifest.
If you see any difference between the two, it might mean that a library or dependency you're using in your project is limiting your project's audience.

You can view how Android studio is merging your manifest file with the dependencies, see: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html#inspect_the_merged_manifest_and_find_conflicts